# How to have an API call working? Currently my call to client is not working

Tags: c#, api, .net-5

I have an API in .net 5 that runs locally.  One of the endpoints is https://localhost:44362/User

Now, I created a console app that will consume the API and defined a method to call the get User.

```
    public async Task<bool> CallAPI()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44362/");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("User"))
            {
                var resContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Here is the code in the API

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        using (var context = new ohabartContext())
        {
            return context.Users.ToList();
        }
    }
```

But when the code using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("User")) is executed nothing happens.  I don't receive any error or whatsoever.  I search the net and all other codes look the same in consuming or calling an API.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to help you figure out the issue.

Comment: Make sure to `await` `ReadAsStringAsync` rather than using `.Result`. Is the `CallAPI` call being awaited as well?

Comment: Look at the console output of the API project as it's running, or use a network sniffer such as Fiddler or Wireshark. See what http url the code is actually producing. Put down breakpoints in your API project to see if the endpoint is being executed.

Comment: there is no output at all

Answer (score 0):

`ReadAsStringAsync()` Serialize the HTTP content to a string as an asynchronous operation. This operation will not block. The returned Task object will complete after all of the content has been written as a string.

```
HttpResponseMessage response= await client.GetAsync(u);
var resContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Once the operation completes, the Result property on the [returned task object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=net-6.0) contains the string with the HTTP content.

```
        public async Task<bool> CallAPI()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44362/");

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(u);
                    var resContent = awit response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} " , e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-6.0

Comment: when it execute  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(u); still, nothing happens.

Comment: @rjuy Nothing Happens is the debut studio album by American band Wallows, released on March 22, 2019 through Atlantic Records.